# lazarus on mac os x 10.4

Tags: macos, lazarus

I tried to install lazarus on a mac os x 10.4 macbook but it did not work, can any one give me a hint on how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at CodeTyphon (http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=148), and ask author if Mac will be supported. CodeTyphon already has 4 host layers and 16 target layers, and it is the easiest cross platform Lazarus/FreePascal single step installation package.

Answer (score 1):

I used the latest 3 packages from sourceforge:

fpcsrc-2.2.4-intel-macosx.dmg
fpc-2.2.4.intel-macosx.dmg
lazarus-0.9.28.2-i386-macosx.dmg

When I click the lazarus icon nothing happens

Comment: It is an Intel macbook? It doesn't happen to be ppc or so?

Answer (score 0):

I tried on OSX 10.6 the release 0.9.28.2 and everything works fine.

Try http://lazarus.firmos.at/index.php?topic=7126.0

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this. Happy New Year